# WPF listview RAM increases enormously

Tags: wpf, windows, listview, caliburn.micro, ram

I have a list of 100 items. I have to refresh my list every 1min. Every time I update the list - RAM increases.

```
private BindableCollection<MyObject> _list = new BindableCollection<MyObject>()
```

As I said every 1min I have to update my list, so I have an event that fires every 1 minute.

```
private void OnListChanged(List<MyObject> list) {
    _list.Clear();
    _list.Addrange(list);
}
```

After an event occurs, RAM increases about 10-20mb. The problem is that RAM is never decreased... Looks like GC does not collect the garbage.

I tried to update show only the first 10 items and update only first 10 items, RAM was still increasing, but slower.

For view, I'm using ListView:

```
<ListView
    BorderThickness="0"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemView}"
    Focusable="False" />
```

I tried like that:

```
<ListView
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="15"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Item"
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemView}"
    Focusable="False" />
```

But Virtualization didn't help either...

What I saw that if I comment listview before running code. RAM doesn't increase anymore, so It's definitely something bad with Bindings...

Could someone please help me, explain to me where is the problem?

P.S. If it's relevant I'm using Caliburn.Micro.

**EDIT**

P.P.S. I've tried to run GC manually, but nothing happened.

P.P.P.S. I've tried to monitor with memory analyzers and everyone shows me that it's unmanaged memory, and I don't understand what to do next...

**EDIT**

What I found:

> Yes, using List.Clear() clears the references to all objects in the
>   list and sets the Count property to 0. It does not release the
>   reference to the underlying array that stores the object references.
>   You can set the Capacity property to 0 after clearing it to release
>   the reference to that array.
>
> If you actually have OOM problems then doing this is not exactly a
>   cure, it can create more address space fragmentation trouble. Check
>   this answer for hints on how to avoid creating too much garbage in the
>   Large Object Heap.

But BindableCollection doesn't have the capacity or possibility to clear the capacity.

**EDIT**

I unsubscribed from all events I was subscribed to and made my list update with a button click. Still the same issue...

Comment: "Looks like GC does not collect the garbage." did you tried to call `GC.Collect` manually to see if it works?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu updated my question

Comment: are u using `ICommand` inside `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu I do not use commands

Comment: could you show more coding to see how you update your list and so on..? are you using eventaggregator event? it will be interesting to see your coding about listviewmodel

Comment: @Frenchy the update is already been shown.

Comment: need code about listviewmodel...

Comment: what does MyObject contain

Comment: @BenSteele Just some strings, ints and that's it

Comment: have you checked listview and listwiemodel are released from memory when you clear _list...?

Comment: Take a memory dump and load it into PerfView. It will show you which data is rooted by it. If it is unmanaged memory it could be that you have many large bitmaps rooted which allocate on the managed side only a BitmapHandle but large amounts of unmanaged memory.

Comment: @Frenchy read my second **EDIT**

Comment: Probably no solution for your problem, but I think CacheLength needs to be two values like: CacheLength="15,15" for the cache before and after the visible items. But I think virtualisation shouldnt be the reason. It should only effect how much ram it uses loading the list once and how much time it takes. (did you try out listbox, or is that no option? i think it performs better than listview)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similary project (cockpit builder) where i bind a lot of different views
A solution to check if viewmodel and view associated are released from memory:

you could put destructor like this: i display message in output view but you could set a breakpoint for debugging

```
    ~ListViewModel()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Listviewmodel released");
    }
```

and the same for list in ListView.xaml.cs

```
    ~ListView()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Listview released");
    }
```

if you are using EventAggregator event dont forget to unsuscribe if you have subsribe to an event..  if you dont do that, the view and viewmodel are not released.

if you suspect the bindcollection to use lot of ram why you dont do that?:

```
private void OnListChanged(List<MyObject> list) {
    _list.Clear();
    _list = new BindableCollection<MyObject>()
    _list.Addrange(list);
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because my _list is bound to ICollectionView. After new BindableCollection is created, my CollectionView won't be notified about changes.